# mixin media with breakpoint and custom value

Tags: sass

---

I tried to use this mixin for media queries in SASS.

```
$breakpoints: (
  extrasmall : 480px,
  small : 600px,
  medium: 768px,
  large : 1025px
) !default;

@mixin media($keys...) {
    @each $key in $keys { 
        @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, $key)){
            @content;
        } 
    }
}
```

The breakpoints works fine and I'm particulary glad of it, BUT I have an exception

```
.slider {
        justify-content: flex-start;
        @include media(715px) {
            justify-content: center;
        }
}
```

What can I change in my mixin to accept breakpoints OR custom value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this one option would be to use an `@if` and `@else` statement to check if there is a custom value. I had to change your mixin slightly to get this to work:

```
$breakpoints: (
  'extrasmall' : 480px,
  'small' : 600px,
  'medium': 768px,
  'large' : 1025px
) !default;

@mixin media($break, $customValue, $custom: false) {
  @if $custom {
    @media (min-width: $customValue){
      @content;
   } 
  } @else {
  $value: map-get($breakpoints, $break);
  @media (min-width: $value) {
    @content;        
  }
}
} 
  
.test{
  @include media(medium,0,$custom: false){
    display: flex;
  }
}

.slider {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  @include media('',"715px", $custom: true) {
      justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Another option (without changing your mixin) would be to create a new mixin to merge a new value with the `$breakpoints` map, since [maps are immutable](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps#immutability). Your new mixin would look something like this:

```
@mixin add-breakpoint($size, $width) {
  $breakpoints: map.merge($breakpoints, ($size: $width)) !global;
}
```

Then you would use this mixin in your SASS like so:

```
@include add-breakpoint("slider", 715px);
```

and then

```
.slider {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  @include media("slider") {
      justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Also, it is typical to put the map keys in quotations, here is the entire example:

```
@use "sass:map";

$breakpoints: (
  'extrasmall' : 480px,
  'small' : 600px,
  'medium': 768px,
  'large' : 1025px
) !default;

@mixin media($keys...) {
    @each $key in $keys { 
        @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, $key)){
            @content;
        } 
    }
}

@mixin add-breakpoint($size, $width) {
  $breakpoints: map.merge($breakpoints, ($size: $width)) !global;
}

@include add-breakpoint("slider", 715px);

.slider {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  @include media("slider") {
      justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the advices Bert. Your help was precious.

Comment: You're welcome @DavidSTEVENOOT. If the answer is working for you it's customary to mark it as accepted and even upvote it if you like it.